# Convert file to two dimensional array with java 8 Files.lines stream

Tags: java-8, nio

I have file with some matrix data:

*data.txt*

```
0 4 8 5 7
4 0 5 9 3
8 5 0 6 2
5 9 6 0 1
7 3 2 1 0
```

I'd like to read it from file and convert to two dimensinal array using beautiful Files.lines stream.
So my strugglings:

```
int[][] arr = Files
        .lines(Paths.get("somepath/data.txt"))
        .map(item -> item
                .chars()
                .filter(i -> (char) i != ' '))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
```

Not actually working) (at least two dim list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parse each line you read as an int array, and then collect all those arrays into your multi-dimensional array.

```
int[][] arr = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get("somepath/data.txt"))
         .map(item -> item.chars().filter(i -> (char) i != ' ').map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray())
         .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

You may also use `Pattern#splitAsStream` to parse each line:

```
.map(item -> Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(item).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
```

Note that it's also recommended to use a try-with-resources statement with `Files.lines`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure String::trim is way better though

Comment: @PaulLemarchand `String.trim()` will remove leading and trailing whitespaces, but not the spaces in-between

Comment: But performing `Pattern.compile(" ")` again in each line is not very efficient.

Comment: It can be easily extracted into a variable beforehand.